# datediff function is always returning null

Tags: mysql, sql

```
SELECT datediff(Contract_Start_Date,Contract_End_Date) FROM testdata;
```

this query is always returning `null`

my date is

```
Time ID        Date
TIME_101    2011-12-12
TIME_102    2011-12-13
TIME_103    2011-12-14
TIME_104    2011-12-15
TIME_105    2011-12-16
TIME_106    2011-12-19
TIME_107    2011-12-20
TIME_108    2011-12-21
TIME_109    2011-12-22
```

and

```
Contract ID Contract Start Date Contract End Date
CON_001          TIME_101         TIME_1248
CON_002          TIME_102         TIME_1249
CON_003          TIME_103         TIME_1250
CON_004          TIME_104          TIME_1251
CON_005          TIME_105         TIME_1252
CON_006          TIME_106         TIME_1253
```

I need to fetch the difference between Contract Start Date and Contract endDate

Comment: You need to join the other table.

Comment: If you do `SELECT Contract_Start_Date,Contract_End_Date FROM testdata`, do you get useful dates?

Comment: What database are you using? (oracel, mysql, mssql?)

Comment: **Contract_Start_Date and Contract_End_Date**. Those fields, is it from same table?

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: @Arion It's which *DBMS* are you using? A *database* is a collection of data.

Comment: @Colin'tHart : Right. Thanks for point that out

Answer (score 1):

Ensure that you are comparing date representations rather than codes ('2011-12-12', not 'TIME_101'; are you performing the correct join between the two tables?) and that those representation are parsed into dates using the correct format (which doesn't appear anywhere in your question).

Comment: i am using mysql
can u help me in wriitng the join query

Comment: my test data contains  time id

Answer (score 0):

T-SQL Query to calculate date difference:

```
select Contract_ID, datediff(Day,Contract_Start_Dt,Contract_End_Dt) as [Datediff]
from 
(
    select TD.Contract_ID,
    (
        select T1.[Date]
        from table1 T1
        where T1.Time_ID = TD.Contract_Start_Date
     )  as Contract_Start_Dt 
    ,
    (   select T1.[Date]
        from table1 T1
        where T1.Time_ID = TD.Contract_End_Date 
    )  as Contract_End_Dt
    FROM testdata TD 
) as T
```

[EDIT: To get a count of contracts when there is a difference between start date and end date grouped by month following T-SQL query will work]

```
select COUNT(*) 
from 
(
select Contract_ID,Contract_Start_Dt,Contract_End_Dt, datediff(Day,Contract_Start_Dt,Contract_End_Dt) as [Datediff]
from 
(
    select TD.Contract_ID,
    (
        select T1.[Date]
        from table1 T1
        where T1.Time_ID = TD.Contract_Start_Date
     )  as Contract_Start_Dt 
    ,
    (   select T1.[Date]
        from table1 T1
        where T1.Time_ID = TD.Contract_End_Date 
    )  as Contract_End_Dt
    FROM testdata TD 
) as T) as T1
where [Datediff]>0 -- case when there exists a difference between two dates
group by MONTH(Contract_Start_Dt)
```

Hope this helps!!!

Comment: Yes, just ensure that date column in your table is of date or date-and-time data type for Datediff function to work.

Comment: can i value in date be 01/01/2012

Comment: this is not working i need the count of contracts also when there is a differnce group  by month

Comment: What is the data type of Date column in your first table?

Comment: i am giving an example  here suppose i have raised a ticket on 2012-01-01 and assigned to person on 2012-01-02 and the ticket is closed on 2012-01-04 but the expected closure is on 2012-01-03 i need to find the differnce between the closed date and excpected closed date  and do a group by on month .

Comment: Contract_End_Date column in your second table has values which don't have corresponding data in your first table. Is this a case with your main data as well or it's just you have posted sample data here. Because if i create a sample data in second table with a row as ('CON_001','TIME_101 ','TIME_102') above query works perfectly fine.